# How to get the run command in log file in Python

Tags: python

How to get the run command in log file in Python ?

I had run the below command in command line and want to print the same command in log file so i can use that command from log file and can run it again.

Example:
python checkcelllist -c celllist -s ronak.lib

it should print above command in log file.

python checkcelllist -c celllist -s ronak.lib

Answer (score 3):

You can dump the contents of `sys.argv` to the file:

```
print >> logfile, ' '.join(sys.argv)
```

Note that this doesn't include the interpreter (`python`), only the script name and arguments.

If your arguments can contain spaces:

```
print >> logfile, ' '.join([(repr(arg) if ' ' in arg else arg) for arg in sys.argv])
```